# New York timezone with Python

Tags: python, django, timezone

I want to serve my Django app the current time which clients will parse this datetimestamp with Javascript. I include my timezone as such:

```
Apr 30, 2012 12:38:08 -400n
```

I currently use the following way to do this:

```
datetime.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S -400n")
```

However the end partm `-400n` is problematic, light saving and all others and it can change, simply harcoding will be nonesense, is there another way to  automatically achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to django 1.4, then read the [documentation on timezone support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/), which is a new feature for 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another library. I've used both [PyTZ](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).